# delete previous content from JTable every time button event happens

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm having a hard time removing data from my JTable. I've tried JTable .repaint(), setRowCount(0) , also model.removeRow(). I created print statements to see the row count when using setRowCount and the rows do become 0 however my table does not update. This is the last part of this project I need to implement. I'm not sure why my table isn't updating because I am altering the model with removeRow as well as setRowCount. If you guys could guide me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

```
public class TemplateGui extends JFrame  {
    private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private JTextField textField;
    private static String [] sortedRoles_Flags,finalFlagsArr,finalHSArr;
    private static String finalFlags="",finalHS="",columnToConvert="Result";
    private Vector<String> SF,HS,column;
    private JTable hotelSecurityTable,securityFlagsTable;
    private DefaultTableModel hsTableModel,sfTableModel;


    public TemplateGui(){

        super("Galaxy Template Generator V1.0");
        //column name
        column = new Vector(Arrays.asList(columnToConvert));

        getContentPane().setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));

        //radio buttons
        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Central User ");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton);
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setBounds(222, 75, 127, 36);
        getContentPane().add(rdbtnNewRadioButton);

        final JRadioButton rdbtnPropertyUser = new JRadioButton("Property User");
        rdbtnPropertyUser.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        rdbtnPropertyUser.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnPropertyUser);
        rdbtnPropertyUser.setBounds(222, 38, 127, 34);
        getContentPane().add(rdbtnPropertyUser);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        textField.setBounds(10, 35, 53, 34);
        getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblHotelSecurity = new JLabel("Hotel Security (H S)");
        lblHotelSecurity.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblHotelSecurity.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblHotelSecurity.setBounds(10, 144, 189, 23);
        lblHotelSecurity.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 204));
        lblHotelSecurity.setOpaque(true);
        getContentPane().add(lblHotelSecurity);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Security Flags (S F)");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        label.setBounds(222, 144, 372, 23);
        label.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 204));
        label.setOpaque(true);
        getContentPane().add(label);

        JLabel lblEnterTemplateCode = new JLabel("ENTER TEMPLATE CODE");
        lblEnterTemplateCode.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblEnterTemplateCode.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblEnterTemplateCode.setBounds(10, 9, 175, 23);
        getContentPane().add(lblEnterTemplateCode);

        JLabel lblSelectUserRole = new JLabel("SELECT USER ROLE LEVEL");
        lblSelectUserRole.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblSelectUserRole.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblSelectUserRole.setBounds(222, 13, 195, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblSelectUserRole);

        //Submit button action
        Button button = new Button("Generate Template");
        button.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 12));
        button.setBackground(new Color(102, 255, 102));
        button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        button.setBounds(467, 83, 127, 41);
        getContentPane().add(button);


        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                Query excell = new Query();
                //get template text
                String template = textField.getText().toUpperCase();
                System.out.println(template);

                if(rdbtnPropertyUser.isSelected()){
                    try {
                    //property user was selected
                        excell.runProcess(1);
                        System.out.println("you selected Property user");
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    try {
                    //Central User was selected 
                        excell.runProcess(2);
                        System.out.println("you selected central user");
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("NOW WERE HERE");
                //get static variables from Excel Query 
                for(int i = 0; i< Query.sortedGF.length; i++)
                {
                    if(Query.sortedGF[i].contains(template)){
                         sortedRoles_Flags  =Query.sortedGF[i].split(" ");
                         System.out.println("THIS RAN"+" :"+i); 
                         break;
                    }

                }

                //add data to table
                int j=1;
                int sizeOfFlags = Query.securityFlags.length;


                //Add HS to FinalHS Variable only if Yes
                for(int i=0;i< sortedRoles_Flags.length+1-sizeOfFlags;i++)
                {
                    if(sortedRoles_Flags[i].matches("Y|y|Y\\?|\\?Y|y\\?|\\?y"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Hotel security:"+" "+sortedRoles_Flags[i]+" HS Added: "+Query.hotelSecurity[i]);
                            finalHS += Query.hotelSecurity[i]+"+";
                            System.out.println("Hotel security:"+" "+finalHS);
                        }
                }

                //add Security Flags to Final Flags
                for(int i=(sortedRoles_Flags.length-sizeOfFlags+1);i< sortedRoles_Flags.length;i++)
                {                   
                        finalFlags += Query.securityFlags[j]+"\t\t: "+ sortedRoles_Flags[i]+" + ";
                        j++;
                }

                //Leave open just incase they would prefer a text file for template in which case we just write it
                System.out.println(finalFlags);

                System.out.println(finalHS);

                //Convert to String Arrays in order to add to our JTable
                finalFlagsArr= finalFlags.split("\\+");
                finalHSArr = finalHS.split("\\+");

                for(int i=0; i <finalHSArr.length;i++)
                    finalHSArr[i].replaceAll(" ","");

                hsTableModel.setRowCount(0);
                for (String row : finalHSArr) {
                    hsTableModel.addRow(new Object[]{row});
                }
                sfTableModel.setRowCount(0);
                for (String row : finalFlagsArr) {
                    sfTableModel.addRow(new Object[]{row});
                }

            }
        });
        //scroll panes for flags
        JScrollPane scrollPaneHS = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPaneHS.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPaneHS.setBounds(10, 170, 189, 185);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPaneHS);

        JScrollPane scrollPaneSF = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPaneSF.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPaneSF.setBounds(222, 170, 372, 187);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPaneSF);

        //tables for updates
        hsTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(HS,column);
        hotelSecurityTable = new JTable(hsTableModel);
        hotelSecurityTable.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        scrollPaneHS.setViewportView(hotelSecurityTable);

        sfTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(SF,column);
        securityFlagsTable = new JTable(sfTableModel);
        scrollPaneSF.setViewportView(securityFlagsTable);


    }


}
```

**Update**
my latest attempt. It seemed to work but not the second time around.

```
if(hsTableModel.getRowCount() !=0 && sfTableModel.getRowCount() !=0){
                    for(int i=0; i<hsTableModel.getRowCount();i++)
                        hsTableModel.removeRow(i);

                    for(int i=0; i<sfTableModel.getRowCount();i++)
                        sfTableModel.removeRow(i);

                    sfTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(0, sfTableModel.getRowCount()-1);
                    hsTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(0, hsTableModel.getRowCount()-1);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setRowCount(0) works.

I was forgetting to reset the string Values of 
finalHS =""; finalFlags=""; Therefore the table was printing out the values stored in the variable.

I had the variables obtain their data through += Method as seen below. 
Next time I will SSCCE before posting.

```
 for(int i=0;i< sortedRoles_Flags.length+1-sizeOfFlags;i++)
                {
                    if(sortedRoles_Flags[i].matches("Y|y|Y\\?|\\?Y|y\\?|\\?y"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Hotel security:"+" "+sortedRoles_Flags[i]+" HS Added: "+Query.hotelSecurity[i]);
                            finalHS += Query.hotelSecurity[i]+"+";
                            System.out.println("Hotel security:"+" "+finalHS);
                        }
                }

                //add Security Flags to Final Flags
                for(int i=(sortedRoles_Flags.length-sizeOfFlags+1);i< sortedRoles_Flags.length;i++)
                {                   
                        finalFlags += Query.securityFlags[j]+"\t\t: "+ sortedRoles_Flags[i]+" + ";


   j++;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

> when using setRowCount and the rows do become 0 however my table does not update.

Since you are using a DefaultTableModel, the setRowCount(0) is the proper method to use to clear the model of all the entries. The should automatically repaint itself.

Create a simple [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. The `SSCCE` should consist of a JTable with data, and then a JButton to invoke the setRowCount() method.

Prove to yourself that the basic concept works and then determine why you real code doesn't. If the table does not repaint then it usually means you are invoking the setRowCount() method on a TableModel that has NOT be added to the JTable that is visible on the GUI.

Also, don't:

1. use Button. You should be using a JButton
2. use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with Layout Managers.

Comment: I will test and report back

Comment: getContentPane().setLayout(null);
My layout is Null btw

Comment: @ArkhamRejek, I know the layout is null, I suggest you should NOT use a null layout.

Comment: Ahhhhh I will make note for future programs thank you very much for your help. I just printed everything out on a smaller scale I noticed my error.